# How to quote field names in FireDAC in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm working on an application that runs on multiple databases, many of which have their own way of quoting reserved words as field names for example
For example

```
select `key` from mytable
```

or

```
select "key" from mytable
```

or

```
select [key] from mytable
```

I was wondering if there was a preprocessor command (or some other mechanism) that could automatically determine the correct quote characters to use for a given database.  And yes (before someone comments) I shouldn't use reserved words for field names, but the schema is already predefined (a couple decades ago).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a constant SQL command string you can use the **{id}** identifier substitution [**escape sequence**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences). An example usage:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT {id Key} FROM {id MyTable}';
FDQuery1.Open;
```

For assignments from code you can use [**substitution variable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables) macros with [**AsIdentifier**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDMacro.AsIdentifier) accessor. An example usage:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT &KeyCol FROM &TheTable';
FDQuery1.MacroByName('KeyCol').AsIdentifier := 'Key';
FDQuery1.MacroByName('TheTable').AsIdentifier := 'MyTable';
FDQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: Nice, escape sequences are exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just be careful at [possible conflict with reserved chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43465988/8041231) when macro preprocessing is enabled. Make sure to properly escape all _special_ chars in your SQL commands (if your commands use any).