# the database column is not found even though it exists (firedac)

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac

There is this listbox which gets populated with the name of the columns of a database in Delphi (Radstudio, Firedac). Depending on the listboxitem selected by the user, the data of the relevant column should then be loaded into another listbox.

To read that specific column I use the following code:

```
SQL.Add ('SELECT '  
     + QuotedStr(Trim(ListBoxName.Selected.Text))
     + ' from TABLE_NAME');

open;
```

so far so good.
However, when I try to access the data of the column, an error is raised saying the 'Field ... not found'.

```
ListBoxItem.Text := VarToStr(FieldValues[ListBoxName.Selected.Text]); ==> Field 'field_name' not found!
```

I guess the problem is with the qoutedstr() in the first line. But not using it causes errors with the name of the columns with numbers and . in them.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont know, what is your DB, but try to use '"' + Trim(ListBoxName.Selected.Text) + '"'

Comment: @da-soft I use sqlite database, and this worked. Thank you.

Comment: @da-soft ``QuotedStr`` should do the same job. But it would be much better to use a parameterized query!

Comment: @hsh_Ar you should clear the ``SQL`` property before adding a new query. Or use ``SQL.Text :=`` instead.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I do clear the SQL beforehand : 'SQL.Clear'

Comment: @DelphiCoder I'd like to know more about parameterized query in my case. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries

Comment: @DelphiCoder Most databases do not allow query parameters to be used in a `SELECT` field list, though. But there are other ways to address this issue, see [How to quote field names in FireDAC in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875203/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, I've overseen that detail!

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the SQL query `SELECT 'field_name' from TABLE_NAME`, in other words you are returning a string literal, not the contents of a named table field. That is why `FieldValues['field_name']` is not able to find such a field in the result set - it really doesn't exist.

Since your selected text is the name of a table field, you need to drop the `QuotedStr()`:

```
SQL.Text := 'SELECT ' + Trim(ListBoxName.Selected.Text) + ' from TABLE_NAME';
Open;
```

You will then be executing the SQL query `SELECT field_name from TABLE_NAME`, and then `FieldValues['field_name']` will work.

If you still get errors on the `field_name`, then the field's name likely contains reserved characters that need to be escaped, but using `'...'` is not the right way to escape them.  Depending on your database, you may need to use `` `...` `` or `"..."` or `[...]` instead.

Or, you can use FireDAC's ["identifier substitution escape sequences"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences) or ["substitution variables"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables) features instead, let FireAC handle the database-specific escaping for you.  Have a look at [How to quote field names in FireDAC in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875203/) for examples.

Comment: when I drop the `QuotedStr()`, error occurs in case there is decimal point in the field name. but the identifier substitution worked.

Comment: @hsh_Ar "*error occurs in case there is decimal point in the field name*" - that would fall under the "field's name likely contains reserved characters that need to be escaped" statement in my answer.